# Extending vuetify 3 v-app-bar and keeping layout with v-navigation-drawer & v-main

Tags: vuetifyjs3

I have created a component called "TitleBar" that basically controls v-app-bar and how its various parts are composed.

Its template literally starts with v-app-bar. The rendered DOM is equal to using v-app-bar instead of TitleBar.

Now, to my problem:

It seems Vuetify's layout code only recognises v-app-bar as a component where it will place v-navigation-drawer & v-main below the app bar. It won't recognise TitleBar as v-app-bar and thus renders v-navigation-drawer OVER the TitleBar and v-main UNDER it.

In generated CSS, this is reflected on the v-navigation-drawer's & v-main's top & height attributes that both have the constant set to 0 instead of 64px.

I looked at the Vuetify code and I just can't find the code responsible for this to find a good workaround. I'd appreciate a pointer to that code too.

I have also not found anything in the Vuetify documentation: there's just no mention of creating aggregate components that would utilise v-app-bar like I'm attempting to do.

What else can I try to get the layout to be composed as I want it?

(just to be clear, I want it to look like [this example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/wireframes/system-bar/), only without the system bar)

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone stumbles upon a similar issue:

The problem originates in my custom component not being one of the recognised [application layout components](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/application-layout/) in Vuetify.

I have now "fixed" my problem by changing my component to use toolbar instead of app bar - and then wrapped my component in an app bar.

The actual change to toolbar was necessary, otherwise v-main would calculate double top offset for itself.